# Positioning of elements From The Window

Tags: javascript, css, position

I am having this piece of javascript ->

```
    const items = [...document.getElementsByClassName("todo")].map(
    (li) => li.innerText
  );
  const items2 = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("position"));
  let results = [];
  let mapped = items2.map((items) => items.name);
  items.forEach((item) => {
    let index = mapped.indexOf(item);
    if (index > -1) {
      results.push(items2[index]);
    }
  });
  let matcheditems3 = results;
  const fakeImages = document.querySelectorAll(".todo");
  for (let i = 0; i < matcheditems3.length; i++) {
    if (matcheditems3[i].name === fakeImages[i].innerText) {
      const name = matcheditems3[i].name;
      fakeImages[i].style.position = "relative";
      fakeImages[i].style.left = matcheditems3[i].positionInfoX + "px";
      fakeImages[i].style.top = matcheditems3[i].positionInfoY + "px";
      fakeImages[i].style.bottom =
        Number(matcheditems3[i].positionInfoY) +
        Number(matcheditems3[i].positionInfoHieght) +
        "px";
      fakeImages[i].style.right =
        Number(matcheditems3[i].positionInfoX) +
        Number(matcheditems3[i].positionInfoWidth) +
        "px";
      fakeImages[i].style.minWidth = "300px";
    }
  }
```

This positions the div(s)  according to the items in the array
That works fine !!

But as you can see the element's position is set to  'relative'.
So it adds, to the left, right, top and bottom,  whatever value from its **current position**

Can I achieve something like ->
It adds the the px from the window itself !!

Any idea ?
Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No problem !! 
I found out the solution !!!   You can use JQuery

```
for (let i = 0; i < matcheditems3.length; i++) {
if (matcheditems3[i].name === fakeImages[i].innerText) {
  const name = matcheditems3[i].name;
  $(fakeImages[i]).offset({
    top: matcheditems3[i].positionInfoY,
    left: matcheditems3[i].positionInfoX,
  });
}  


}
```